# What does this line of python code means

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

I am using paramiko in Python to sftp files to remote machine, rest of code makes sense to me but this specific line am not understanding what it does

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
```

What is transport?

This is the whole code:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.put(localPath, remotePath)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

What I understand is that it makes the socket, I might be wrong, please someone clarify this to me in most simple terms.

Comment: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/transport.html ...

Comment: It's an object of class `paramiko.Transport`. Have you looked at the documentation for Paramiko?

Answer (score 0):

SSH's full RFC title is ["SSH Transport Layer Protocol"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt) and it typically is another layer above TCP/IP.

Very simplified explanation for the transport function.  It is in effect creating a secure connection from your machine to the remote like running a steel conduit from one building to the next.  A passerby can't see what is in the conduit.

SFTP is a sub-protocol of SSH and behaves like a cable being run down the SSH steel conduit.  It is possible to have multiple SFTP connections running down the same SSH connection simultaneously which connect not only to the remote server but to other machines the remote server has access to.

Putting the above together.  To make a SFTP connection to a remote server, you first have to make a SSH transport connection.